# Mongodb find() query returns nothing while field and value exists

Tags: database, mongodb

I have this simple database with one single collection and when I try a simple query with a field and value that exists il returns nothing.

one row of the database :

```
    {
        "title" : "Cupone Salice Salentino",
        "sku" : 1000126,
        "vendor" : "messapia-tesori-del-salento",
        "image" : "",
        "estimatedprice" : 21,
        "finalprice" : 21,
        "qty" : 1,
        "category" : "Vins & alcools",
        "status" : "fulfilled"
    }
```

Code:

```
db.orders.find();    // this works
db.orders.find({qty : 2});   // this returns nothing
```

Comment: Have you tried calling it with `qty: 1`?..

Comment: yes i tried and it also returns nothing...

Comment: Post your entire Object, right now you have more closing braces than opening braces so I'm guessing you are missing some information.

Comment: yes it's just one row of the database and there is 1227 of them. all the objects have the same structure and fields

Comment: This isn't a full record, otherwise, it would also have an `_id` property

Comment: looks like this document are in another array since it's closing by: `] }`, can you show the full collection results?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not gave whole document here.Because according to me "qty" is in array in your document object that's why.